# Adding rows automatically based on previous rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to get information about room usage by classes at my school. I have used an SQL statement as following:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Room,
                         Subject,
                         COUNT(Subject) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Timetable
GROUP BY Room,
         Subject
ORDER BY t.Room
```

Say I had one room only at my school called `M13`. This SQL statement might give me:

```
Room    Subject    Expr1  
M13     English    7  
M13     Maths      41
```

As you can see, the total usage for this room is 48 classes per timetable cycle. If the total maximum per timetable cycle is 60 periods (6 periods a day x 10 days in a cycle) how can I automatically add a row at the end of each room showing the number of periods the room is not used for ex., a row after the two rows above:

```
Room    Subject    Expr1  
M13     English    7  
M13     Maths      41
M13     Not Used   12
```

Obviously, I would like to do the same for every room in the school but I have just shown 1 room here for simplicity.

I am not sure at all if this is possible or how it could be done so any help at all would be great.

Comment: What kind of SQL server are you using (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, PostgresQL, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're using SQL Server, the only solution that comes to my mind is to UNION the results of two SELECT statements, one in which you select the occupancy of the classes, and one in which you calculate the non-occupancy and union the results.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Room,
    Subject,
    COUNT(Subject) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Timetable
GROUP BY Room,
    Subject

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Room, 
    'Not Used',
    60 - COUNT(Subject) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Timetable
GROUP BY Room

ORDER BY t.Room
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81342f/1) with the query

Comment: No doubt someone will come up with a really hard to read single-query solution, but this one works fine. One question though, what benefit comes from using the TOP (100) PERCENT? It works just as well without it. Does it exploit some intricacy of the execution plan for better performance or something?

Comment: @Zec I honestly have never used it, I was just researching it right now, but if the OP has used it in his attempt, I thought diverging as little as possible from his solution would make him understand my query better.

Comment: Yep. Fair enough. So, OP, What's the dealio?

Comment: @Zec Apparently TOP 100 PERCENT is commonly used for views, so I can assume the OP is going to use this in a view. More details here: http://bit.ly/4UOdAy

Comment: There is no need for the Top (100) Percent. I created the view in Management Studio and it automatically put this in. Thanks for the quick response - I will give this a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Yep. Generated code explains it. Also, Radu, I've used it in ordering a view, just figured it must have some magical properties in this context. It doesn't. There is no Santa.

Comment: @Barrelnc - if this is in a view, you need to be aware that, despite Management Studio inserting the `TOP (100) PERCENT` and `ORDER BY`, and pretending that views can be ordered, the actual result from *querying* the view may be in any order, unless there's an `ORDER BY` on the query that is accessing this view.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - it works fine except for the fact that it gives me separate calculations - it adds 2 rows - for example, it gives me 'Not Used' 53 (This is for English as it uses the room 7 times) and then another row for Maths 'Not Used' 19. (As Maths uses the room 41 times. Is there any way to add up the total room usage first (7 + 41 = 48) and then return only one 'Not Used' row which will be 12? (60 - 48). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Radu - I gave that a go but it still gives me separate results for each subject - nothing has changed. I suppose this is because they are still grouped on the Subject and it counts the number of times the room is used by that subject but it doesn't give me the total at all.

Comment: @Barrelnc I've added a link to a SQLFiddle at the bottom of my answer, check it out, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Radu - thank you again for all your help. My problem was that I was still grouping both the room and the subject in the second select statement. When I removed the subject from the grouping it works great. Brilliant job. All fixed and working perfectly.

Comment: @Barrelnc That explains it, you're welcome. If this has worked for you, please don't forget to mark the answer as the solution.